# PHP - Debugging stalls when it enters file with breakpoints

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

So I have a Laravel application that I am trying to debug from my `PhpStorm`

In PhpStorm I get the message `Debug session was finished without being paused` And if I press `Break at first line` it correctly stops in `server.php`.

Now going through the application and I set a few breakpoints. As soon as the site is about to go to a page where the controller has a breakpoint the server completely stalls and never loads up the page.

As soon as I disable the debugger while it's loading it finishes the loading.

I run the server using `php artisan serve` but have also tried to use PhpStorm's built in web server but without any luck.

Has anyone experienced this issue before and may know how I might fix it?

**More info**

So on my application i have the following file:

**CourseController**

[image]

As you can see i have two breakpoints on this page

When i attempt to go to this site the following happens:

[image]

Basically it loads for ever. it seems that its not even trying to load the files because the log output is:

Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000

Now i stop listen to the page

and it starts loading the page with all of its images and content

Comment: Need more info .. maybe even a screen cast to see what is happening in PhpStorm at that time. Right now ("page stalls") it sound s like you have more than 1 debug session attempted at the same time and if IDE is configured to have only 1, it will wait for that to finish before proceeding with another. You can see the limit in Xdebug section of PhpStorm -- in current IDE for new projects it should be 2 or 3 by default. Older versions/projects created long time ago may still have just 1 there.

Comment: Extra debug session may be coming from a missing resouce (e.g. a typical case would be favicon.ico) when such request is handled by index.php. Need more info as other "nuances" are possible. Overall you can debug in general as I understand. if that's so then this issue from my prev comment is quite likely to be the reason here.

Comment: "Debug session was finished without being paused" message suggests that the code that was executed did not had any breakpoints. Therefore I suggest to also enable and collect Xdebug log and see what file is being executed by PHP, what IDE sends etc. Also check what resources are requested during that time. To easier the debug, try doing that for a page/script that has as little resources as possible (images/css/js) so it's easier to spot the things.

Comment: added more info

Comment: Sadly that info does not give me any better clues. What's your IDE version, Xdebug version? PhpStorm settings for debugging. Try to get Xdebug log -- at least it will tell what may be happening there. Right now nothing concrete comes into my mind.